# Prevent empty XML element to take room

Tags: android, xml

How can I make so that when an element is empty, it simply does not take any room on the screen?

For example on this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:weightSum="1">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_urgence"
                    android:id="@+id/urg"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:id="@+id/TitreSav"
        android:textColor="@color/FrozenBlue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:textColor="@color/FrozenBlue"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView with id : date will sometimes be empty. When it's the case, I don't want it to take any room in my list (see the screenshot for an easier understanding, can't quite find the words in english)
[image]
(I want Hyj to be aligned with the small circle but the empty date is still here under)

I've already tried to set the Visibility to Gone or invisible but I still have the remaining blank space when the date is empty.

Comment: By the way, nested LinearLayouts are often bad for performance

Comment: If the text is empty, Set the visibility of the textview to gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set internal gravity for your `LinearLayout`s

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

especially for parent of your "date" `View`

Comment: can't find  easy solutions when stuck in my head... well thanks mate it worked like a charm